# Retrieving the AD machine account password on an Ubuntu machine

Tags: linux, ubuntu, active-directory, ldap

I'm trying to perform an LDAP query against Active Directory from a script (very similar to [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/276506/active-directory-lookups-from-bound-mac-without-user-credentials)) from a domain-joined Ubuntu machine.  The script can't prompt for a password, as it won't be running interactively.

The linked question uses an OSX-specific tool (`/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy`).  Are there Linux equivalents that I could use to grab the password so I can bind to AD?

Comment: What means "domain-joined machine" in context of Ubuntu? Do you have a domain-joined Samba installation? Or maybe AD-based LDAP/Kerberos authentication enabled in PAM? Can you accept a solution with writing separate LDAP bind password to a protected file?

Comment: Sorry, I should clarify - I'm referring to AD authentication in PAM.  I'd like to avoid hardcoding credentials if possible (which is why I'd prefer to use the machine account).

Comment: LDAP or Kerberos or both? If LDAP only, you probably have your bind password stored somewhere anyway, right? Is the LDAP auth bind user able to read all the requested atributes?